# Testing Outlook VSTO Addins

Tags: testing, outlook, vsto, add-in

I am trying to write a really simple Outlook VSTO add in that checks email that is being sent for a few simple properties. My problem is that I cannot seem to install/test the add in using Outlook. I have added unit tests that ensure the code I have written likely does what it should but that final level of integration eludes me. Any suggestions for how to test my code within Outlook? Thanks in advance.

If you want I can post the code as well and better explain what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are coding in Visual Studio debugging automatically places it in Outlook and Opens Outlook. Just make sure Outlook is closed before starting as this seems to cause issues. Otherwise in your bin folder where your dll was created there is a vsto file, Click on that and it will install it.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will give it a shot. I tried using the VSTO file and that appeared to fail. I also tried F5 debugging but I probably had outlook open at the time. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps. you got lucky because I just started working on vsto this week so I had to figure this stuff out recently ;)

Comment: F5 debugging worked like a charm when outlook was not already started. I have been having alot of issues with the vsto as I think I installed a bad version of the addin and now cannot get rid of it. However, that is not a programming question. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We've also had many issues also around not being able to remove bad add-ins once installed. The usual steps we take are to:

- Uninstall the VSTO add-in (using the vstoinstaller /u command)
- Delete directories within the %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 directory
- Delete directories within the %userprofile%\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3 directory
- Clear the ClickOnce app cache (rundll32 dfshim,CleanOnlineAppCache)

If these all still do not work, one workaround if you would install the vsto add-in outside of Visual Studio (if you would like to do this) is to temporarily change the assembly name in the properties of the main assembly to something else. This then fools Outlook/installer into thinking this is a brand new add-in that has not been seen before.

Hope this helps.